# Converting IMG to BIL/HRD/BLW?

Tags: dem, convert

I'm trying to convert IMG data from USGS's 1/9 arc second DEM to something that Pathloss 5 can read.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

[GDAL](https://www.gdal.org/) can write [BIL files](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#EHdr) (among many [others](https://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html))

```
gdal_translate -of EHDR input.img output.bil
```

GDAL is available for Win, Mac, Linux and other OSs and there are multiple ways to install.